# How to prove $p | a^2 \implies p | a$?

Tags: divisibility

How to prove $p | a^2 \implies p | a$? Given that $a,p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It will be hard. After all, $4\mid6^2$, but $4\nmid6$.

Comment: true if $p$   is squarefree, otherwise false,  take  $p=4, a=2$

Comment: As José notes, this statement is not true. However, assuming $p$ is prime, the statement is true by Euclid's lemma.

Comment: @Joe how about if $p$ is squarefree as mentioned above? Does this automatically imply that $p$ is a prime?

Comment: @jessegerritsen: No, every prime number is squarefree, but not every squarefree number is prime. Assuming you are familiar with the definitions of "squarefree" and "prime", it should be easy to come up with the smallest example of a squarefree number that is not prime.

Comment: @Joe could it also be a relative prime to $a$ or does it have to be an actual prime number?

Comment: @jessegerritsen: If $n|a^2$ and $n$ is coprime to $a$, then $n|a$. However, this theorem is not very interesting because the hypotheses "$n|a^2$" and "$n$ is coprime to $a$" can only be satisfied when $n=1$.

Comment: @jessegerritsen: Let $S$ equal the set of numbers $p$ such that, for all $a$, if $p|a^2$ then $p|a$. It can be proven that $S$ equals the set of squarefree integers. In other words, the set of numbers $p$ for which the implication always holds is precisely the set of squarefree integers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $p$ is prime, $p$ and $a$ have no common divisors other than $1$ if $p \nmid a$. In this case you can use Bezout's lemma to find integers $m$ and $n$ with $am + pn = 1$.  This leads to $a^2m + apn = a$, and since $p|a^2$ there exists $b$ with $bpm + apn = a$. That is, $p (bm + an) = a$, implying $p|a$ after all.

The same argument will work if $p$ is not prime but $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).